# Able to modify hotkeys

Tags: feature-request

I use some hotkeys on my chrome for mac like <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go to the navigation bar but it's getting hijacked by this wysiwyg editor

I also use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page but it's also hijacked by this wysiwyg editor and instead it gives me `----------` it's a bit frustriated

I even wonder why it works - cuz when you get the tooltip from the icon it says you should use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (not <kbd>cmd</kbd>)

---

I would like to see a settings page where we can remap our own hotkeys with a set of default one

Not only for this wysiwyg editor but also for the snippet code editor aswell that lacks hotkeys atm

Comment: Related on MSE: [Keyboard shortcut for formatting posts on Mac should support ⌘](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78599/), [On Mac browsers, ⌘-L should select the address bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/), [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)

Comment: you ain't my cuz